# Multiple files in log4net with same logger

Tags: c#, logging, log4net, appender

I'm currently working in a chat API, and I receive multiple requests at the same time, from different sessions, so its almost impossible to track each 
conversation separately, because it mixes with all the others logs from other conversations.

So I want to create a separated file for each session(conversation) dynamically, with the filename as the sessionId, but if I create multiple loggers, my application just freeze, because I can have more than 100 sessions simultaneously.

I have also tried to change the file path (programmatically) for each request with its id on it, but it also freezes the application after 1-2 hours.

Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: Use some other service for logging to which you can fire and forget the log entry details and have that service to do the business logic around separating the log files.

Comment: Have you experimented with the FileAppender.LockingModel Property to see if a minimal lock would help? Maybe time to look a different tool or storing them in a db.

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius, Thank you for your help! I will probably go that way. I have already tried other loggers solutions but none of them could handle the giant amount of data/different files simultaneously.

Comment: @Kevin, I have tried this option, but I think that the problem is that every time that I receive a request for a new chat session I create a new logger, and I never dispose it as it is an API (it's impossible for me to know if each request will/won't be the last request in the conversation in order to dispose the logger). So I think that the performance issues that I have is all about loggers not being disposed and the amount of CPU that it requires to create a new logger. I have already tried to set FileAppender.LockingModel but it didn't solved the problem.

Comment: That makes sense, I would try Erno's solution below.

Answer (score 1):

If these conversation files are so important, consider other options than logging. A database might be appropriate.

Another solution might be to parse the log files and split them into conversation files in a separate (logical?) process (perhaps later, after the session has ended.) This way the program doesn't need to keep track of many files at the same time and parsing can be done faster/more efficiently.

Comment: I think that I will just do the second option that you have gave me, as I already have everything on db, I just want to have another way to see all the process that runs simultaneously on the same conversation. So I will create another application that just reads the log files of two different applications and splits into each conversation file. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I like that idea, continue using log4net, but parse the files with another process.